# If radio button value changes then submit leads to different page (2) else leads to another page (1)

Tags: javascript, radio-button, submit

Gender:

Male
Female

If value is male then submit button will link to page 0003

If value is female then submit button will link to page 0002
Here I got stuck that through which coding to different page link can be made in submit button  based on radio button value change.

please provide an answer that can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<input type="radio" name="male" id="male" />Check One <br />
<input type="radio" name="female" id="female" />Check Two 
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="chekcSubmitType()"  />


<script>
function chekcSubmitType()
{
    if(document.getElementById('male').checked)
    {
        window.location="first page name"; 
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('female').checked)
    {
         window.location="second page name";
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: not only check if male checked then clicking on submit button leads to a web page and if female checked then submit button leads to different web page.

Comment: i think it doing the same thing u want to do

Comment: How it work : on button click it call the function, function verify which radio button is checked, and according to this it redirect where we want to redirect. see above edited answer